# ASP.NET Core EF Identity and Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, azure-ad-b2c

I want to create an ASP.NET Core 2 app with the EF Core Identity. The next step will be to use the Azure B2C authorization mechanism.

And here's the question - will I have two databases ? One to store user's data (azure b2c) and the second one to store my application business logic data ? Or is it possible to have one DB for my scenario and use it in the same way as always with EF Core Indentity ?

Comment: What is EF Core Identity?  Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

See this guide: [Cloud authentication with Azure Active Directory B2C in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c)